# What does it mean to normalize an email address?

Tags: django, email

In this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), Django talks about normalizing an email address with `self.normalize_email(email)` where `self` is `BaseUserManager`. When I search for "normalizing emails" it seems to be a practice across all platforms. I see tutorials of how to do it, but nothing really explaining what it is and what it's used for.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For email addresses, `foo@bar.com` and `foo@BAR.com` are equivalent; the domain part is case-insensitive according to the RFC specs.  Normalizing means providing a canonical representation, so that any two equivalent email strings normalize to the same thing.

The [comments on the Django method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.2/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L19-L31) explain:

> Normalize the email address by lowercasing the domain part of it.

Answer (score 10):

One application of normalizing emails is to **prevent multiple signups**. If your application lets the public to sign up, your application might attract the "unkind" types, and they could attempt to sign up multiple times with the same email address by mixing symbols, upper and lower cases to make variants of the same email address.

From [Django's repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L19-L31), the docstring of `normalize_email` is the following:

> Normalize the email address by lowercasing the domain part of it.

What this method does is to lowercase the domain part of an email, so this part is [case insensitive](https://www.yourdictionary.com/case-insensitive), so consider the following examples:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
>>> BaseUserManager.normalize_email("user@example.com")
user@example.com
>>> BaseUserManager.normalize_email("user@EXAMPLE.COM")
user@example.com
>>> BaseUserManager.normalize_email("user@example.COM")
user@example.com
>>> BaseUserManager.normalize_email("user@EXAMPLE.com")
user@example.com
>>> BaseUserManager.normalize_email("user@ExAmPlE.CoM")
user@example.com
```

As you can see all emails are equivalent because the case after `@` is irrelevant.